# Can we make some rows non-editable in react-data-grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, react-data-grid

I am using [react-data-grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/) for displaying an editable table in a page. I have used `editable: true` for enabling editable columns. But i have some rows which are non-editable. How can i control this in row-level?

Please suggest a solution. PFB the initialization of data grid.

```
<ReactDataGrid
    enableCellSelect={true}
    columns={this.state.columns}
    rowGetter={rowGetter}
    rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
    rowHeight={35}
    minHeight={500}
    onGridRowsUpdated={this.handleGridRowsUpdated}/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ReactDataGrid takes "editable" as input function.

Here, we can pass out custom logic to determine if edit is allowed for the specific cell.

```
columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        name: 'ID'
      },
      {
        key: 'location_id',
        name: 'Location ID',
        editable: function(rowData) {
          return rowData.allowEdit === true;
        }
      }
]
```

Comment: please let me know where can we get documentation about ReactDataGrid. I found [official site](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/documentation.html#/componentsDocs) only. But couldn't find the details that you have shared.

Comment: I couldn't find this in the documentation as well. I had required similar scenarios then ended up searching their source file file ("react-data-grid.js") for solution.
If you search "canEdit:" in this file you can probably find the comment there about this method.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

Comment: This worked after my two days of search. Hope they create a better documentation